# EF Core DbSet.Add or DbSet.Update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to make a small web application that will store some things in a database. However, I need to check if an entry is already in the database. If so, update it. If not, add it. How would I go about this?

My current approach is this:

```cs
public void Set(string key, string value)
{
    var setting = this.settingsContext.Settings.Where(s => s.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

    if (setting == null)
    {
        this.settingsContext.Add(new SettingModel { Key = key, Value = value });
    }
    else
    {
        setting.Value = value;
        this.settingsContext.Update(setting);
    }
}
```

When doing it using transactions the code gets pretty unwieldy:

```cs
public void Set(string key, string value)
{
    using (var transaction = settingsContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var setting = this.settingsContext.Settings.Where(s => s.Key == key).First();

            if (setting == null)
            {
                this.settingsContext.Add(new SettingModel { Key = key, Value = value });
            }
            else
            {
                setting.Value = value;
                this.settingsContext.Update(setting);
            }
            settingsContext.Database.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            settingsContext.Database.RollbackTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

The slightly unwieldy parameters are because I am implementing the `IConfigurationProvider` interface, not much I can do about that.

Comment: what is not working? Are you asking for a code review? Please be more precise in your question otherwise we could not help you

Comment: if you're still looking for a good approach, I found this one that looks quite ok
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485128/entity-framework-core-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-if-a-generic-entity-is-a